# Convert a string to a Multi-Level Dictionary

Tags: c#, parsing, dictionary

I have a a text file that looks like

```
tabs.main="******"
tabs.settings="******"

settings.setting1="******"
settings.setting2="******"
settings.setting3="******"
settings.setting4="******"

settings.setting5.title="******"
settings.setting5.settingoption1="******"
settings.setting5.settingoption2="******"
```

What I'd like to be able to do is parse this into a multi-leveled dictionary. For example, I'd have a root dictionary that looks like this `Dictionary<string, object>` and in that I would have tabs and settings which were both `Dictionary<string, object>` them selves. In a graphical form what I'd like is:

```
Dictionary<string, object>
   -> Dictionary<"tabs", object>
      -> Dictionary<"main", "*******">
      -> Dictionary<"settings", "*******">
   -> Dictionary<"settings", object>
      -> Dictionary<"setting1", "*******">
```

And so on and so forth. Is this possible? And if so, could someone give me a pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are going to run into is that some of your keys are going to need to be stored in the dictionary with values (strings presumably) and some of them will need to be stored with Dictionaries.

In your example you listed:

```
settings.setting5="******"
settings.setting5.settingoption1="******"
```

These two lines contradict each other.  settings.settings5 would have the key settings5 store a value in the dictionary, but the next line is expecting settings5 to be a dictionary of other values.

You could write a block of code like this:

```
var settings = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("...");
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var parts = line.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2);
    if (parts.Length != 2) continue;

    var keys = parts[0].Split('.');
    var value = parts[1];

    var dict = settings;
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(keys[i]))
            dict.Add(keys[i], new Dictionary<string, object>());
        dict = (Dictionary<string, object>)dict[keys[i]];
    }

    dict.Add(keys[keys.Length - 1], value);
}
```

1. It doesn't have any error checking.
2. You'll find that while it does populate your objects.  It is a pain to retrieve values from it.  Since you have to cast each result to either a string or another Dictionary.

Either way you'll find that you will most likely want to avoid trying to creating dictionaries of dictionaries for this purpose.

Comment: I know, I realized this after I posted my question. I've modified it accordingly. This is actually how I ended up doing it! And the pain is actually handled in the DynamicObject I'm going to use to access the dictionaries!

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries aren't really designed to hold your data in that manner.  You could create classes to represent your file and load the data into them instead.  Based on what you've shown something like this might work.

```
public class File
{
    private List<Setting> settings = new List<Setting>();
    public Tab Tab { get; set; }
    public List<Setting> Settings { get{ return settings; } }
}

public class Tab
{
    public string Main{ get; set;}
    public string Settings{ get; set;}
}

public class Setting
{
    private List<string> options = new List<string>();
    public string Value{ get; set; }
    public List<string> Options{ get{ return options;} }
}
```

Comment: This is going to be used in a DynamicObject Deserializer so having a predefined class layout wouldn't be optimal. However, this is how I would have done it if the content was static! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using an object other than a dictionary, but to answer your question.

Note that this data structure does not allow both a dictionary and a string value with the same key.

```
static Dictionary<string,object> Parse(string contents)
{
   var root = new Dictionary<string,object>();

   using (var rdr = new StringReader(contents))
   {
      string line;
      var equals = new [] {'='};
      while(null != (line = rdr.ReadLine()))
      {
         if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
         {
            var keyValue = line.Split(equals, 2);
            AddValue(root, keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
         }
      }
   }

   return root;
}

static void AddValue(Dictionary<string,object> dict, string dottedKeys, string value)
{
   string [] keys = dottedKeys.Split('.');
   for(var i = 0; i < keys.Length - 1; i++)
   {
      var key = keys[i];
      dict = GetOrAdd(dict, key);
   }
   dict[keys[keys.Length - 1]] = value;
}

static Dictionary<string,object> GetOrAdd(Dictionary<string,object> parent, string key)
{
   object o;
   Dictionary<string,object> childDict;
   if(parent.TryGetValue(key, out o))
      childDict = (Dictionary<string,object>) o;  // This will throw when adding a dictionary to a value.
   else
      parent[key] = childDict = new Dictionary<string,object>();
   return childDict;
}

static string fileContents=@"
tabs.main=""******""
tabs.settings=""******""

settings.setting1=""******""
settings.setting2=""******""
settings.setting3=""******""
settings.setting4=""******""
settings.setting5=""******""

settings.setting6.settingoption1=""******""
settings.setting6.settingoption2=""******""
";
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up managing to right some code myself in the time being, but as I hate to have wasted peoples time answering this question, I'll mark Jason's question as the answer as it is kinda what I came up with and he helped me write my code!

```
Dictionary<string, object> _dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
{
    string text;
    while ((text = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (text.Equals(String.Empty))
            continue;
        string line = text.Trim();
        string[] keyval = line.Split('=');
        string value = keyval[1].Trim('"');
        string[] keys = keyval[0].Split('.');
        Dictionary<string, object> prevDic = _dic;
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i + 1 != keys.Length)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> temp = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                if (prevDic.ContainsKey(keys[i]))
                {
                    prevDic = prevDic[keys[i]] as Dictionary<string, object>; // Avoids exceptions when trying to cast the string value to a dictionary
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    prevDic.Add(keys[i], temp);
                    prevDic = temp;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                prevDic.Add(keys[i], value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for everyones help in this!